# jQuery Product Count?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a nice alphabetical filter in jQuery that seems to work quite well. Here it is working: http://staging.morningsidepharm.com/products/generic-medicines/

Essentially it sits atop a list of products and then filters them when you click on a letter. Here's the code it's using:

```
// Alphabetical Filter for Products

var $boxes = jQuery('.elementor-posts-container > .elementor-post');

var $btns = jQuery('.alphabet-btn').click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  if (id == 'all') {
    $boxes.show()
  } else {
    $boxes.hide().filter(function() {
      var re = new RegExp('^' + id, 'i');
      return re.test($(this).text().trim());
    }).show()
  }
  $btns.removeClass('alphabet-active');
  $(this).addClass('alphabet-active');
});
```

Along with this HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="alphabet-active alphabet-btn alphabet-all" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="a">A</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="b">B</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="c">C</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="d">D</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="e">E</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="f">F</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="g">G</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="h">H</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="i">I</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="j">J</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="k">K</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="l">L</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="m">M</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="n">N</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="o">O</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="p">P</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="q">Q</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="r">R</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="s">S</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="t">T</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="u">U</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="v">V</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="w">W</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="x">X</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="y">Y</button>
<button class="alphabet-btn" id="z">Z</button>
```

and this CSS:

```
.alphabet-btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #1b91c3;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.alphabet-btn:hover {
  background-color: #134583;
}

.alphabet-active {
  background-color: #134583;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.alphabet-all {
  width: 100px;
}
```

A few, more complex filters I have seen provide a product count when you hover over them like this:

[image]

Would anyone know of a way to add this functionality to my existing filter?

I assume I will need something to count each letter on load and then display it on hover... I'm not even sure if its possible with the approach I've taken?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Many thanks!

Comment: some idea ---https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/button-badge.html

Comment: Thanks - this will help me to style it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the basics  of what you already have to give you a count for each letter when page loads.

Loop over all your alphabet elements , filter the boxes that match and get the length of that collection. then append or prepend another element in each letter and add a bit of style to position it and round it out etc

```
$('.alphabet-btn').each(function() {
  var id = this.id;

  var count =  $boxes.filter(function() {
      var re = new RegExp('^' + id, 'i');
      return re.test($(this).text().trim());
    }).length

  $(this).append('<span class="count">' + count +'</span>')
});
```

You could also use this to add a class to each box like `box_a, box_c, ...box_z` etc and simplify the other filtering by just looking for that matching class

Comment: That's perfect, thanks so much! I just have to style them as you said and try to make them appear only on hover - All of which I believe I can do via CSS :) Thanks again.

Comment: Apologies, charlietfl while this works great I have a tiny issue :) the Show all button, on hover, shows '0' - it there a way to exclude the class .alphabet-all from having the count added?

Comment: `$('.alphabet-btn').not('#all').each..`

Comment: Where abouts would this go, charlietfl ? I've tried to add it below the .append line, and tried various things but it doesnt seem to have any effect... do I need the .each.. on the end? or should it just end with a semi-colon? Sorry to keep asking questions :)

Comment: No...it is the start .... just insert the `not()` part before the current `each` in my answer

Comment: Oh, I understand - apologies :) Thanks again for all your help!